# How to get different edge styles in the same tree

Tags: forest, trees

I'm using `forest` to make a tree with the `forked edges` option. I would like to be able to combine this with `sn edges`. Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}

\usepackage[edges,linguistics]{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
forked edges, for tree={font=\sffamily}
[ABC
    [A1
        [A2]
        [A2]]
    [B1]
    [C1, sn edges
        [C2]
        [C2]]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

So, for instance, I would like node C1 have its children with the `sn edges` option, but apparently the `forked edges`option at the beginning forces the whole tree to have that style.

Comment: Do you mean that you don't want all of the edges to be `forked`? Or do you mean that you want to combine `forked` with `sn edges`? The former I understand and is easy: `forked edge` applies only to the current edge (as opposed to `forked edges` which affects the whole tree). The latter I don't understand at all, so I don't know whether it is easy, difficult or impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks downright peculiar to me, but this site is concerned with technical implementation and not with the wisdom of implementing things.

That said, the question is not at all clear. This is just the best interpretation I could come up with.

[image: best interpretation]

If I had to guess what you want, as opposed to what you say you want, I'd guess you wanted instead something like the following.

[image: best guess]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges,linguistics]{forest}
\forestset{%
  declare boolean={fork me}{false},
  fork my edges/.style={%
    for tree={fork me},
    before typesetting nodes={%
      where fork me={forked edge}{},
    },
  },
  fork me not/.style={%
    fork me=false,
    sn edges,
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  fork my edges,
  for tree={font=\sffamily}
  [ABC
    [A1
      [A2]
      [A2]]
    [B1]
    [C1, fork me not
      [C2]
      [C2]]]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  fork my edges,
  for tree={font=\sffamily}
  [ABC
    [A1
      [A2]
      [A2]]
    [B1]
    [C1, for descendants={fork me not}
      [C2]
      [C2]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: 1. Your guess was right, that is what I wanted and I thank you for your answer. Sorry if I wasn't clear!

Comment: @ledb612 Aha! So you wanted to change the option for the node's descendants and not for that node at all.

Comment: That is correct. I thought I said it when I mentioned I wanted C1 to have its children with th sn edge option but now I see it was not clearly expressing my idea. The second tree inyour code is exactly what I needed. Thanks again!

Comment: @ledb612 You did. But you added the option to the C1 node and not its children and I guess I focused on that, since it sounded as if you wanted an exception for a single node. Anyway, glad it is all sorted!